# Doubt about diffused mode

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, brain

Is the diffuse mode  (the default mode network)  basically mind wandering mode(daydreaming mode)  recruits neurons within the prefrontal cortex  in addition to the cingulate, joining them to the hippocampus OR is the diffuse mode subconscious(feeling/emotion) which functions through amygdala....

Comment: We require questions to use references/citations to frame things in something from psychology or neuroscience. So, what have you read about these concepts? Where are the alternatives you propose coming from?

Comment: @BryanKrause I was reading The organized mind by Daniel J. Levitin where he talks about  mind wandering mode and its origin in the brain . And since we know the feeling/ emotion originates in amygdala my question was that which part is responsible for Diffused/open mode of thinking (IS it amygdala or prefrontal cortex)

Comment: Please add citations and quotes and such to your question rather than responding in a comment. Thanks! Especially about this "diffused mode", as this seems to be a very non-standard term.